# Looping in HTML5

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm pretty new to this whole html thing. I made this code which allows me to set 2 pictures, e.g. a start and a stop. When 'start' is clicked it should also play a looped audio file which should stop when 'stop' is clicked.

Although the audio stops when I click 'stop', the audio does not loop when playing!

Help would be mucho appreciated...o

This is in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function imageSwitch(_imgID,_imgStart,_imgStop,_soundFile) {
this.imgID = _imgID;
this.imgStart = _imgStart;
this.imgStop = _imgStop;
this.soundFile = _soundFile;

this.pos = 0;
this.e;

this.change = function() {
if(this.pos == 0) {
this.pos = 1;
document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStop;

this.e = document.createElement('embed');
this.e.setAttribute('src','https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/MP3/Waves.mp3');
this.e.setAttribute('id','sound'+this.imgID);
this.e.setAttribute('hidden','true');
this.e.setAttribute('autostart','true');
this.e.setAttribute('loop','true');

document.body.appendChild(this.e);
} else {
this.pos = 0;
document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStart;
this.e.parentNode.removeChild(this.e);
}
}
}
```

This is also in the head:

```
var wave = new imageSwitch('btn1','https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/OMAA/Waves2PNG.png','https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/OMAA/Active/Waves%20Active%20PNG.png','https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/MP3/Waves.mp3');
```

This is in the body:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 60px;"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/OMAA/Waves2PNG.png"
                             width="331" height="96" border="0" alt="one" onClick="wave.change()" id="btn1" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK, I'd rather use [Audio api](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

The problem in your code, you can't access wave object inside onclick event. Make it global you'll see that works.

```
wave = new imageSwitch('btn1','https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/OMAA/Waves2PNG.png','https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/OMAA/Active/Waves%20Active%20PNG.png','https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/MP3/Waves.mp3');
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v97Kq/)

## UPDATE-1

And here is the better way, with Auido Object, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v97Kq/1/)

```
function imageSwitch(_imgID, _imgStart, _imgStop, _soundFile) {
    this.imgID = _imgID;
    this.imgStart = _imgStart;
    this.imgStop = _imgStop;
    this.soundFile = _soundFile;
    this.song = new Audio(this.soundFile);
    this.song.loop = true;
    this.pos = 0;
    this.e;

    this.change = function () {
        if (this.pos == 0) {
            this.pos = 1;
            document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStop;
            this.song.play();
        } else {
            this.pos = 0;
            document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStart;
            this.song.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE-2

For cross browser, you should define different source, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v97Kq/3/)

```
wave = new imageSwitch('btn1', 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/OMAA/Waves2PNG.png', 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/OMAA/Active/Waves%20Active%20PNG.png', 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39640025/MP3/Waves.mp3','https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39640025/OGG/Waves.ogg');

function imageSwitch(_imgID, _imgStart, _imgStop, _soundFileMp3, _soundFileOgg) {
    this.imgID = _imgID;
    this.imgStart = _imgStart;
    this.imgStop = _imgStop;
    this.song = new Audio();
    if (this.song.canPlayType("audio/mpeg"))
        this.song.src = _soundFileMp3;
    else 
        this.song.src = _soundFileOgg;
    this.song.loop = true;

    this.pos = 0;
    this.e;

    this.change = function () {
        if (this.pos == 0) {
            this.pos = 1;
            document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStop;
            this.song.play();
        } else {
            this.pos = 0;
            document.getElementById(this.imgID).src = this.imgStart;
            this.song.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This now does not work in firefox however. Any ideas how it could be made cross compatible?

Comment: Firefox cannot play mp3 file, you must add an alternate audio source like ogg or wav, [here](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/) you can see which formats are supported by different browsers. and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_src) is the method to add different source. if you can't achive this problem, let me know I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [audio element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio) instead of embed.

Check out its api - there is a "loop" attribute for, well, looping.

In order to determine which image to show, you have to be listening to the audio element's *play*, *pause*, etc. events.