# how to start an mp3 file with a mouse click

Tags: html, click, mouse

I am trying to make a website and I would like to start a sound when you click anywhere on the page (eg its hitmarker when mouse click anywhere on the page).
I have tried many things, but none on work (onclick, href ...).

```
<input type="button" value="play" onclick="play(darude.mp3)"> , 
<a href="#" onMouseOver="PlaySound('darude.mp3')">play</a>
```

Is this possible to make that ?

I want to do that : http://twerkclan.github.io/mlg-userscript/

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955183/play-mp3-with-javascript-html5)

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Xitas I tried with a button and links <input type="button" value="play" onclick="play(darude.mp3)"> , <a href="#" onMouseOver="PlaySound('darude.mp3')">play</a>

Comment: Then add you code in your question and let us help you make it better.

Comment: @MeshBoy answer is not really what I want. I want a sound that triggers anywhere on the page, so in the html body, not just with click on a picture or on a link, like that : http://twerkclan.github.io/mlg-userscript/

Comment: I have update the fiddle check it now. now the code will trigger when you click anywhere in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

var onClick = function() {
    audio.play(); // audio will load and then play
};

button.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
```

[**Working code**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8J26/273/)

And to call function on click anywhere. You should call the function when the user click in the html `body` tag.

Comment: Is it possible to play the song without clicking the text but also in the empty spaces around ?

Comment: yes in fiddle the body curtain only text but in page the body also curtain also the empty parts.

Comment: now i have updated fiddle you can see now sound will play when you will click on empty spaces

Comment: Ok I will try with .js file and .html file

Comment: If i want to play my own song (og test.mp3), I write :  <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="test.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /> but it does not work

Comment: I think there will be some issue in your audio file but i think you will make it work cause you have working code now